Why can't I record my x-y mouse coordinates without artifacts?
I’m developing a Python script to record and replay mouse movements and keyboard actions, but I’m facing issues with mouse accuracy during capture and playback. The movements recorded are often incomplete or too slow when replayed, and sometimes the coordinates are inaccurate, causing the mouse to "jump" or miss small adjustments. The code captures events with pyautogui and keyboard in one thread, appending them to a JSON file for playback. I've tried adding a minimum movement threshold and timing adjustments, but the replayed movements are still not smooth or accurate.
Any advice on fixing this issue or alternative methods to accurately capture and reproduce mouse movements would be helpful.
What I tried:

Adjusted Minimum Distance Threshold: We set a minimum distance for mouse movement capture to reduce jittery recordings of minor movements, but this didn’t improve smoothness during playback.

Adjusted Recording and Playback Intervals: We modified the recording frequency (intervals between captures) to capture more precise positions but found that increasing or decreasing frequency didn’t solve the smoothness issue.

Limited Movement to Active Window: We restricted mouse movements to the active window to address potential synchronization issues caused by recording movements outside the intended area.

Separate Threads for Mouse and Keyboard Actions: To prevent one type of input from slowing down the other, we ran mouse and keyboard actions in separate threads.

Experimented with pyautogui and pynput Libraries: We explored using both pyautogui and pynput for mouse capture, with pynput providing better but still inconsistent results.

Reduced Data Volume: We attempted capturing fewer points by increasing the threshold for minor movements, but it resulted in jerky playback rather than improving speed or smoothness.


FILENAME = "recorded_actions.json"
recording = False
actions = []

# Set recording interval to 50 ms and minimum coordinate change for recording
recording_interval = 0.05  # 50 ms for optimized speed
min_mouse_move = 5  # Minimum coordinate change for recording
last_x, last_y = pyautogui.position()  # Initialize coordinates

# Function to start recording
def start_recording():
    global recording, actions, last_mouse_time, last_x, last_y
    recording = True
    actions = []
    start_time = time.time()

    # Initialize variables to track time and last position
    last_mouse_time = start_time

    # Get active window dimensions
    hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    window_left, window_top, window_right, window_bottom = rect

    def record():
        global last_mouse_time, last_x, last_y
        while recording:
            x, y = pyautogui.position()
            current_time = time.time()

            # Check if mouse is within the active window boundaries
            if window_left <= x <= window_right and window_top <= y <= window_bottom:
                # Record movement if within boundaries and movement threshold met
                if (current_time - last_mouse_time >= recording_interval and
                    abs(x - last_x) > min_mouse_move and abs(y - last_y) > min_mouse_move):
                    actions.append({"type": "move", "x": x, "y": y, "time": current_time - start_time})
                    print(f"Recorded movement to ({x}, {y})")
                    last_mouse_time = current_time
                    last_x, last_y = x, y  # Update last position

            time.sleep(0.01)


you probably should rely on the mouse movement event instead.
